# Excel - Need sumif formula to leave cell blank if blank but show 0 if 0 is present

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a project which I am really struggling with.

[image: current screenshot here]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I need the blue cell in column H to be blank if the formula does not produce a result, but I also need it to display a 0 if the blue cell in column Z has a 0 and this needs to be linked to the job number in column B, which is also in column T.

I have tried and had a working solution with VLOOKUP but this is not viable as the same job number may appear in column T multiple times and it needs to calculate the total of all the values in column Z which relates to column B & T

I don't even know if this is possible but given how powerful of a tool excel is, surely this must be

If this is not possible, another option which I also do not know how to do, would be to apply conditional formatting - I was thinking if all of the cells in columns U - AD contained ANY value that linked to the job number in column B, it would change the cells in columns D-I light green to show the record is complete?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the formula *as text*. Function `ISNUMBER` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula basically says:

```
=IF(Sum(...) = "", "", something_else)
```

But the sum of some numbers cannot be an empty string, so that condition will never be met, so the `something_else` will be evaluated.

If propose the following modification:

```
=IF(Sum(...) = 0, "", something_else)
```